# Designing an Interface with long running task

Tags: c#

i am about to design an interface, which contains a function that triggers a long running operation.

now i am not sure if i should offer this in the interface itself or is it up to the caller to decide if he wants to call it blocking or async.

```
public interface I {

    int PerformTask(); // blocks long time

    void PerformTaskAsync(); // returns immediately
    event Action OnTaskFinished(int result); // triggers when task is finished
}
```

should i have both ways in the interface or decide up to one? if so, which one?

Comment: Providing one interface seems to minimize the number of unit tests you have to write.

Comment: Current .NET code uses tasks instead of the EAP pattern you posted. If you provide an interface like the one you posted, your clients will be forced to adapt it to a Task in order to combine it with other asynchronous code. Just provide a single `Task<int> PerformTaskAsync()` method and let the clients call it as `int result=await  obj.PerformTaskAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the architecture where this interface lives.

If the environment is built with the guidelines/practices to decouple client side when necessary, use the blocking call. If the environment has guidelines/practices to expect short delays use the asynchronous version.

If you can use C#5, consider PerformTaskAsync to return a Task so that clients can easily wait for completion if required.